# Using recode in dplyr with inequalities

Tags: r, dplyr

Is it possible to recode a variable using an inequality in recode in dplyr?

```
 x <- 1:10
recode(x,x>5= 11)
```

I've looked around a bunch and can't find if this is possible.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of `recode`, just use `ifelse(x>5,11,x)`.

Comment: `replace(x, x > 5, 11)`

Comment: @alistaire That is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
x[x>5]<-11
```

Comment: I wanted to know if there was a way to do it with recode

Comment: And you said that `case_when` is what you was looking for in the comment above.